# How would I set individual colours for each widget item?

Tags: python, css, pyqt, pyqt4

I have written the code below:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.central_widget = QtGui.QStackedWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.central_widget)
        Login_Widget = LoginPage(self)
        self.central_widget.addWidget(Login_Widget)
        self.central_widget.setCurrentWidget(Login_Widget)
        self.setStyleSheet("background-color:#FFDA00;")

class LoginPage(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(LoginPage, self).__init__(parent)
        self.Username = QtGui.QLineEdit(self)  
        self.Password = QtGui.QLineEdit(self)
        self.Password.setEchoMode(QtGui.QLineEdit.Password)
        self.buttonLogin = QtGui.QPushButton('Login', self)
        self.cancelButton = QtGui.QPushButton('Cancel', self)
        loginLayout = QtGui.QFormLayout()
        loginLayout.addRow("Username", self.Username) 
        loginLayout.addRow("Password", self.Password)
        horizontallayout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        horizontallayout.addWidget(self.buttonLogin)
        horizontallayout.addWidget(self.cancelButton)
        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addLayout(loginLayout)
        layout.addLayout(horizontallayout)
        self.setLayout(layout)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()
```

With the code above, When I run the code, it sets everything orange. I wanted to set the background orange, the `lineedit` white and the buttons silvery-grey. How would I set different colors for individual `widget` items?? Also is there any way that I could set a colour for the Window bar (the bar containing the window-title, exit button, minimize button, and re-size button)

Any help will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set different style properties for individual widgets.

Have a look at this link [Qt Style Sheets Examples](http://qt.developpez.com/doc/4.7-snapshot/stylesheet-examples/) as it cover how to set different style properties for most of the widgets.

You can also save the stylesheeet as `.qss` file and save it externally.

```
css = '''

QMainWindow
{
background:orange;
}   

QLineEdit
{
background:white;
}

QPushButton
{
background:qlineargradient(x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1,
                          stop: 0 #FAFFFA, stop: 0.4 #F5F7F5,
                          stop: 0.5 #F0F2F0, stop: 1.0 #EDEDED); 
}
'''

class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.central_widget = QtGui.QStackedWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.central_widget)
        Login_Widget = LoginPage(self)
        self.central_widget.addWidget(Login_Widget)
        self.central_widget.setCurrentWidget(Login_Widget)

class LoginPage(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(LoginPage, self).__init__(parent)
        self.Username = QtGui.QLineEdit(self)  
        self.Password = QtGui.QLineEdit(self)
        self.Password.setEchoMode(QtGui.QLineEdit.Password)
        self.buttonLogin = QtGui.QPushButton('Login', self)
        self.cancelButton = QtGui.QPushButton('Cancel', self)
        loginLayout = QtGui.QFormLayout()
        loginLayout.addRow("Username", self.Username) 
        loginLayout.addRow("Password", self.Password)
        horizontallayout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        horizontallayout.addWidget(self.buttonLogin)
        horizontallayout.addWidget(self.cancelButton)
        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addLayout(loginLayout)
        layout.addLayout(horizontallayout)
        self.setLayout(layout)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyleSheet(css)#<------------set your stylesheet
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()
```

As for the window title bar, it is not possible to set color or any properties. Your best bet is to hide it and implement your own window title bar.